# make current locale as selected getting syntax error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local

I am creating a language switcher in Next.js. It is working fine, but I would like the current language to be selected by default. Therefore, I am doing as follows.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function LanguageSwitcher() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className="form-select-wrapper mb-4">
      <select className="form-select" onChange={(e) =>
          router.push(
            {
              pathname: router.pathname,
              query: router.query,
            },
            null,
            { locale: e.target.value }
          )
        }
      >
        <option value='en' {router.locale === 'en' ? 'selected' : ''}>English</option>
        <option value='fr'>Français</option>
        <option value='hi'>हिंदी</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

its showing syntax error, please help.

please help

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue in your code. In JSX, you should use the selected attribute without an equal sign to conditionally apply it based on a condition. Here's the corrected code:

```
<option value='en' selected={router.locale === 'en'}>English</option>
<option value='fr' selected={router.locale === 'fr'}>Français</option>
<option value='hi' selected={router.locale === 'hi'}>हिंदी</option>
```

In JSX, the boolean attributes like **selected** should either have a value of true to include them or be omitted to exclude them. This way, the selected attribute is only added when the condition (router.locale === 'en', etc.) is true.

Comment: i did by : <select defaultValue={router.locale}>

Comment: Did it work for you or are you still facing issues?